# specify file path when calling matlab

Tags: matlab

I usually call a matlab file on Ubuntu with the following syntax

```
matlab -nodesktop -nosplash -r script
```

I need to call the script from within a folder like the following

```
matlab -nodesktop -nosplash -r folder/script
```

except that matlab throws an error saying

```
undefined function or variable 'folder'
```

How can I do so?

Comment: Try using the full path instead.

Comment: same error, it still sees the path as a file name.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
matlab -nodesktop -nosplash -r run('absolute/path/to/script.m')
```

`run` should also work with relative paths. Then, make certain that your MATLAB session is started in the correct folder, such that the relative path you pass to `run` is correct.

Comment: Try with the absolute then. If that does work there is a mistake in specifying the relative path and you need to fix it.